# How come the indexed type is `never`

Tags: typescript

```
type X = { aa: number; bb: string };
const get = <Key extends keyof X>(key: Key) => {
  type T<Value extends X[Key]> = Value;
  const a: T<any>;
  /**
   * Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'X[Key]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
   */
  const b: T<string>; 
};
```

From my opinion, `Value` should be of type `string|number`, how it was calculated as `never` by typescript

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the ‍`get‍` function in such a way that when it calls, it can be given any type as a generic parameter, that is the subset of `X` keys.
So the condition in `T<Value extends X[Key]>` is ambiguous for typescript.
For example :

`get<"aa">("aa")` results `T<Value extends number>`

`get<"bb">("bb")` results `T<Value extends string>`

`get<"aa" | "bb">("bb")` results `T<Value extends string | number>`

Thus when you do `const b: T<string>;`, it does not know what the condition exactly is and it says:

`Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'X[Key]'`

I don't know the purpose of the function in your project, but I think it can be rewritten in this way using conditional types:

```
type X = { aa: number; bb: string };
const get = () => {
  type MyType<Value, K extends keyof X = keyof X> = Value extends X[K] ? Value : never; 
    const a: MyType<any> = true;  //------> any other value can be assigned
    const b: MyType<string> = "Test"; // -------> it is string type 
};
```

I hope it helps you.

By the way you can read more about conditional types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).